# How to stream my .wmv movies to Apple TV using VLC with MacOS Lion?

Tags: appletv, airplay, streaming, vlc

I want to stream videos (several formats) but I don't want to convert it before to Apple format (H264).

Is there any free option that supports subtitle files? How to stream using VLC?

Comment: You need to explain more. what type video format do you not want to convert from.  What OS are you using. You have asked three questions. Are they really all related to the title question or are they questions that should be asked separately. Please be more clear and explain more

Comment: I need to stream any kind of video format to Apple TV, with subtitles.

Answer (score 1):

Beamer seems to work, take a look here : http://beamer-app.com/

Comment: I bought him. No free option available nowadays.